# GMP division segfault

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, gmp

I'm trying to build a library that does various mathematical operations with GMP so I can use it in place of floats, but I very quickly ran into issues because division doesn't appear to work.  I tried the following in the console:

```
php > $a = gmp_init ("5");
php > $b = gmp_init ("2");
php > echo gmp_add ($a, $b) . PHP_EOL;
7
php > echo gmp_sub ($a, $b) . PHP_EOL;
3
php > echo gmp_mul ($a, $b) . PHP_EOL;
10
php > echo gmp_div_q ($a, $b) . PHP_EOL;
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I got the same result with the other GMP division functions.  As far as I can tell I'm not doing anything wrong.  In fact I even tried the examples directly from the PHP documentation and got the same result (a segfault).

I also tried it with values that can divide exactly and still got segfaults.

PHP version is:

> PHP 7.1.0 (cli) (built: Dec  2 2016 09:19:56) ( NTS )

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

EDIT: As it's a segfault I've logged a bug report for this issue.  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73780

Comment: It does seem to work in PHP 7.0 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, so it's possibly an issue with the Liip PHP build for OSX

Comment: Damn it. Arrived here with exactly the same issue!